# Clojure, file to byte array?

Tags: clojure

I have a .bson file that I need to add to a byte array before decoding it.

I was wondering if anybody has a solution for how to add a file to a byte array using Clojure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most succinct method is just to use the [byte-streams](https://github.com/ztellman/byte-streams) library, in which you'd simply call `(byte-streams/to-byte-array (java.io.File. "path"))`.

If you want to do it without an external library, it would be something like:

```
(let [f (java.io.File. "path")
      ary (byte-array (.length f))
      is (java.io.FileInputStream. f)]
  (.read is ary)
  (.close is)
  ary)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `with-open` for the `FileInputStream`?

Answer (score 2):

somewhat similar to zack's answer,
from [clojure-docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/input-stream)

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn file->bytes [path]
  (with-open [in (io/input-stream path)
              out (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.)]
    (io/copy in out)
    (.toByteArray out)))

(file->bytes "/x/y/z.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

[These days](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-) you can also do:

```clj
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(-> "path/to/thing" io/file .toPath java.nio.file.Files/readAllBytes)
```